# How to assert a antlr common tree using testng?

Tags: java, testng, antlr, antlr3

I am doing a common tree enrichment with a specific data and when I am testing the api using a testng unit test , it shows me the following error.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [START] but found [START]
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:494)
at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:123)
at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:165)
```

I have tried the Soft Assert api of Testng which is also not working. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Is there any way to assert the contents of an object using Testng ?